# React TinyMCE - set initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I am using the `react-tinymce` component to implement TinyMCE in my React app.

I am implementing this component as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TinyMCE from 'react-tinymce';

class Textarea extends Component { 

  constructor(props) {
    //...
  }

  render() {

    return (

        <TinyMCE
          name={this.props.name}
          content={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
          config={{
             plugins: 'autolink link image lists print preview code',
             toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
          }}
        /> 
    )
  }    
}
```

Im passing `this.props.value` to this component which contains a string representing some HTML.

```
<Textarea value={data.body} />
```

The TinyMCE editor renders but there is no content initialized in the editor.

How can I set the initial value in using `react-tinymce`?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? I am facing the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to put a `textarea` inside of TinyMCE? The result will be TinyMCE's textarea editor wrapping your own, raw text editor.

If that is what you're trying to achieve, note that `TinyMCE` takes HTML, not JSX. Also note that `textarea` displays its children elements as the default value, not a `value` attribute. For those two reasons, you want the prop to be formatted like `` content={`<textarea>${data.body}</textarea>`} ``. For your case to illustrate (you'll probably want to manipulate the prop in your parent component):

```js
  render() {
    const propValuePlaceholder = `<textarea>${data.body}</textarea>`;
    return (
      <TinyMCE
        name={this.props.name}
        content={propValuePlaceholder}
        onChange={this.handleFieldChange}
        config={{
          plugins: 'autolink link image lists print preview code',
          toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code'
        }}
      />
    )
  }
```

Comment: please note the Textarea component wrapping the TinyMCE component is just named that way. It actually has a prop (not shown) where I can select a plain textarea or TinyMCE but never both at once

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I read that too literally. In that case, I don't see a problem with your code. Are you setting `data.body` correctly to be a string of HTML?

Comment: yes, `data.body` is an HMTL string and initializes a standard `textarea` if I set it as the value

Comment: Could you include more code in your question? All that works as expected for me: https://codepen.io/tadasant/pen/djvpWP

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with this TinyMCE React wrapper, however, tfrom the docs it seems to expect tags enclosing content as a string.  Are the props you are passing enclosed as tags?  If not, have you tried using a template literal to get the desired outcome?

```
`<p>{this.props.value}</p>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `content={this.props.value}`, change it to `value={this.props.value}`

(this works with TinyMCE version 5.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the TinyMCE React component (as described in https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-add-tinymce-5-to-a-simple-react-project/), you can set the initial value with the [initialValue](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#initialvalue) property.